# Flink TableEnvironment.create throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-flink, flink-table-api

I am testing flink hive connector, following the instruction here https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/hive/overview/.

The final code is as follows. I tried to run it in Intellij IDE. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. TableEnvironment.create throws NoSuchMethodError

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.inStreamingMode();
    TableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings); // throws NoSuchMethodError

    String name            = "myhive";
    String defaultDatabase = "default";
    String hiveConfDir     = "/Users/gaoxiahong/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/conf";

    HiveCatalog hive = new HiveCatalog(name, defaultDatabase, hiveConfDir);
    tableEnv.registerCatalog(name, hive);

    tableEnv.useCatalog(name);

    System.out.println(tableEnv.executeSql("show tables"));
}
```

Exception message is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.config()Lorg/apache/calcite/sql/parser/SqlParser$Config;
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerContext.lambda$getSqlParserConfig$1(PlannerContext.java:263)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerContext.getSqlParserConfig(PlannerContext.java:257)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerContext.createFrameworkConfig(PlannerContext.java:148)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerContext.<init>(PlannerContext.java:130)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.<init>(PlannerBase.scala:116)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.StreamPlanner.<init>(StreamPlanner.scala:62)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.DefaultPlannerFactory.create(DefaultPlannerFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.PlannerFactoryUtil.createPlanner(PlannerFactoryUtil.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.create(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.create(TableEnvironment.java:93)
    at com.yqg.flinkhive.Test.main(Test.java:18)
```

My flink version is 1.15.2 and hive version is 3.1.2. The pom.xml file looks like:

```
<properties>
    <flink.version>1.15.2</flink.version>
    <hive.version>3.1.2</hive.version>
    <scala.version>2.12</scala.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-hive_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>${hive.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table-planner_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Can anyone help me figure out the issue here? Thanks in advane~

Answer (score 0):

Per https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/configuration/overview/ you most likely need to swap `flink-table-api-java-bridge` to `flink-table-api-scala-bridge_2.12`.

See also https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/hive/overview/#program-maven